# 我的奥克兰，我的家 - good or not?

Tags: word-choice, phrase

I'm attempting to express the sentiment "My Auckland, My Home" in Chinese. This is meant to be a slogan suitable for merchandise, e.g. printing on a T-shirt or a coffee mug. I want to convey the sense "I live here, in this place. This is where I feel at home". Auckland, New Zealand is the name of the place. In Chinese, this is 奥克兰.

I need the input of a native speaker to tell me whether the phrase 我的奥克兰，我的家 successfully expresses this in idiomatic Chinese or not.

家 means "home" of course, but I'm not sure whether that can be extended outside the literal house you live in, to encompass a whole city where you feel at home. I feel 家乡 might be more correct but 1) it's too many characters and 2) it seems rural but Auckland is a city.

Is my slogan 我的奥克兰，我的家 a good one? Would you put it on a T-shirt?

Comment: It is fine, the meaning of 家(home)  can extend beyond "one's own house" and describe the city and the place you live in. You can even say "The Earth is my home" because you live on Earth

Comment: Thanks @Tang Ho!
If I were talking about 家乡, would it have the sense of a rural village? E.g. if someone was born in Zhengzhou would it sound funny for them to say 郑州是我的家乡?

Comment: You can say Canada is your 家乡 if you were born there (usually say that when you are located somewhere else), similarly, you can say The earth is your 家乡 when you were somewhere else in the universe, so, if you were born in Zhengzhou and living in Hong Kong, Zhengzhou is your 家乡, Hong Kong is your 家

Answer (score 1):

> I live here, in this place. This is where I feel at home

maybe:

### 奧克蘭・我鄉關・適斯樂土兮忘返

that, it’s rhyming: 蘭 laan4, 關 gwaan1, 返 faan2

the meaning is roughly:

奧克蘭: auckland

我鄉關: my homeland

適斯樂土兮忘返 come to this promised land, forget to return :)

which presumed you’re not born in auckland

have fun :)

Comment: Great, I like it! You win a T-shirt with 奧克蘭・我鄉關・適斯樂土兮忘返 written on it! Also applicable for Oakland, Ca. Batperson, please send 2 T-shirts!

Comment: @Pedroski, photos please 

Comment: I like it, and I'm sure it sounds even more awesome in Cantonese!